# How to split strings based on backslash with regex in R

Tags: r, regex, string

```
string_dat <- structure(list(ID = c(2455, 2455), Location = c("c(\"Southside of Dune\", \"The Hogwarts Express\")", 
"Vertex, Inc.")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L
))

> string_dat
    ID                                       Location
1 2455 c("Southside of Dune", "The Hogwarts Express")
2 2455                                   Vertex, Inc.
```

I would like to expand the data.frame above based on `Location`.

```
library(tidyr)
> string_dat %>% tidyr::separate_rows(Location, sep = ",")
# A tibble: 4 × 2
     ID Location                    
  <dbl> <chr>                       
1  2455 "c(\"Southside of Dune\""   
2  2455 " \"The Hogwarts Express\")"
3  2455 "Vertex"                    
4  2455 " Inc."
```

Splitting just on `,` wrongly split `Vertex, Inc.` into two entries. Also it did not take care of `c(\"` and `\""` for the first two strings.

I also tried to remove the `c(\"` at the beginning by using `gsub`, but it gave me the following error.

```
> gsub('c(\"', "", x = string_dat$Location)
Error in gsub("c(\"", "", x = string_dat$Location) : 
  invalid regular expression 'c("', reason 'Missing ')''
```

My desired output is

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
     ID Location                    
  <dbl> <chr>                       
1  2455 "Southside of Dune"   
2  2455 "The Hogwarts Express"
3  2455 "Vertex, Inc."
```

********** Edit **********

```
library(tidyverse)
string_dat %>% 
  mutate(
    # mark twin elements with `;`:
    Location = str_replace(Location, '",', '";'),
    # remove string-first `c` and all non-alphanumeric characters
    # except `,`, `.`, and `;`:
    Location = str_replace_all(Location, '^c|(?![.,; ])\\W', '')) %>%
  separate_rows(Location, sep = '; ')

# A tibble: 3 × 2
     ID Location                   
  <dbl> <chr>                      
1  2455 "c(\"Southside of Dune\""  
2  2455 "\"The Hogwarts Express\")"
3  2455 "Vertex, Inc."
```

Comment: Despite appearances there is no backslash in the character value that is given to the interpreter as `c("c(\"Southside of Dune\", \"The Hogwarts Express\")", 
"Vertex, Inc."))`. The backslash you see is acting as an escape character to prevent the double-quote that follows from terminating the character value.

Comment: You need to understand the implications of the fact that the backslash is the escape character for both R and for the regex engine. This "\\\\" as a pattern argument match a single backslash if it were present. The pattern you created is "c" followed by a regex-grouping operator which is what triggered the error condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that combines data cleaning with `separate_rows`:

```
library(tidyverse)
string_dat %>% 
  mutate(
    # mark twin elements with `;`:
    Location = str_replace(Location, '",', '";'),
    # remove string-first `c` and all non-alphanumeric characters
    # except `,`, `.`, and `;`:
    Location = str_replace_all(Location, '^c|(?![.,; ])\\W', '')) %>%
  separate_rows(Location, sep = '; ')
# A tibble: 3 × 2
     ID Location            
  <dbl> <chr>               
1  2455 Southside of Dune   
2  2455 The Hogwarts Express
3  2455 Vertex, Inc.
```

How the regex `^c|(?![.,; ])\\W` works:

- `^c`: matches literal c at the beginning of the string
- `|`: initiates alternation (i.e., "OR")
- `(?![.,; ])\\W`: negative lookahead to assert that any *non-alphanumeric characters* (`\\W` with upper-case "W") are matched *except* any of period, comma, and semi-colon (this exception from the `\\W` character class is implemented by the lookahead)

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I am still getting the incorrect answer with the code you provided. I've edited my original post.

Comment: Hm, I can't tell why that is. The code works on my side. Even if I copy the code you've included in your edit I get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

The `Location` column has a strange data format. In the 1st element, it stores R code, because it's using the `c("s1", "s2")` syntax for a two-element character vector. For the 2nd element, you're missing escaped quotes for this to be valid R code for a one-element character vector.

If I manually edit the 2nd element to add these quotation marks, then we can easily evaluate the R code contained in the `Location` column, and then unnest the resulting list column. This might be easier than attempting to edit the strings programmatically?

```r
library(tidyverse)

string_dat <- data.frame(
  ID = c(2455, 2455), 
  Location = c("c(\"Southside of Dune\", \"The Hogwarts Express\")", "\"Vertex, Inc.\"")
)

string_dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Location = list(eval(parse(text=Location)))) %>%
  unnest(cols=Location)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>      ID Location            
#>   <dbl> <chr>               
#> 1  2455 Southside of Dune   
#> 2  2455 The Hogwarts Express
#> 3  2455 Vertex, Inc.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Suppose you have, not two, but millions of strings, you would think about manually changing things twice ...

Comment: Agreed. I was kinda hoping this was a typo in the original question.